# JQuery Toggle With Plus and Minus Icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two sections namely

```
1. section one

2. section two
```

I'm performing JQuery slide up and slide down between two div sections with plus and minus sign change..currently it works superbly i want to make one small change in my code when i click on section one contents of section two is hidden and vice versa i need both should be opened simultaneously can somebody help me out in achieving it Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/v9Evw/348/

**HTML**

```
<ul id="toggle-view">
    <li >
        <h3 style='background:#4c97d0;color:#fff;'>Section one</h3>
        <span style='background:#4c97d0;color:#fff;' class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Morbi commodo, ipsum sed pharetra gravida, orci magna rhoncus neque, id pulvinar odio lorem non turpis. Nullam sit amet enim.</p>
    </li>
    <br>
    <li>
        <h3 style='background:#4c97d0;color:#fff;'>section two</h3>
        <span style='background:#4c97d0;color:#fff;' class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Morbi commodo, ipsum sed pharetra gravida, orci magna rhoncus neque, id pulvinar odio lorem non turpis. Nullam sit amet enim.</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**JQUERY**

```
var parent = $('#toggle-view'), // storing main ul for use below
    delay = 200; // storing delay for easier configuration

// bind the click to all headers
$('li h3, li span', parent).click(function() {

    // get the li that this header belongs to
    var li = $(this).closest('li');

    // check to see if this li is not already being displayed
    if (!$('p', li).is(':visible'))
    {
        // loop on all the li elements
        $('li', parent).each(function() {

            // slide up the element and set it's marker to '+' 
            $('p', $(this)).slideUp(delay);

        });

        // display the current li with a '-' marker
        $('p', li).slideDown(delay);

    }
    else {
        $('p', li).slideUp(delay);

    }
    $('span',li).toggleClass('glyphicon-plus glyphicon-minus');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the loop which changes the state on all the content areas. You only want to apply it to the selected content.

So now you are saying; if this is open, close it, otherwise open it.

```
if (!$('p', li).is(':visible')) {

  $('p', li).slideDown(delay);

} else {

  $('p', li).slideUp(delay);

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v9Evw/350/

Answer (score 1):

Please find the updated fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/v9Evw/349/

```
//$('li', parent).each(function() {

        // slide up the element and set it's marker to '+' 
        $('p', $(this)).slideUp(delay);

   // });
```

Only selected section will slide instead of section 1 and 2. Please see if this meets ur requirement